# Merge and aggregating two dataframes (with the same columns, but not the total number of columns)

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am trying to join two dataframes, with same columns, however the total number of columns is different.

**Dataframe 1**

```
   SKU     DATA      QV  QC
0   70  2018-01-01  3.0 30.0
1   70  2018-01-02  2.0 20.0
2   70  2018-01-03  1.0 10.0
```

**Dataframe 2**

```
 SKU  LOJA    DATA        PVENDA   QV  QC   ESTOQUE_VENDA ESTOQUE_VENDA_UN_COMPRA CURVA_ABC   FORNECEDOR
1   70  HD01    2018-01-01  14.07   2.0 20.0    539.0   5390.0  S   7355
2   70  HD01    2018-01-02  13.78   2.0 20.0    539.0   5390.0  S   7355
3   70  HD01    2018-01-03  13.78   2.0 20.0    539.0   5390.0  S   7355
```

Both of them have `SKU, DATA, QV, QC`

I have to group by using `SKU, DATA` as index, and sum `QV` and `QC`, keeping the columns from Dataframe 2 that are not common.

**Expected Output:**

```
   SKU  LOJA    DATA        PVENDA   QV  QC   ESTOQUE_VENDA ESTOQUE_VENDA_UN_COMPRA CURVA_ABC   FORNECEDOR
1   70  HD01    2018-01-01  14.07   8.0 50.0    539.0   5390.0  S   7355
2   70  HD01    2018-01-02  13.78   4.0 40.0    539.0   5390.0  S   7355
3   70  HD01    2018-01-03  13.78   3.0 40.0    539.0   5390.0  S   7355
```

When I try this :

```
pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1).groupby(['SKU', 'DATA'], axis=1).sum()
```

But I got the following error:

```
ValueError: Grouper for 'SKU' not 1-dimensional
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pd.concat(df1.align(df2, 'inner', 1)) \
  .groupby(['SKU', 'DATA'], as_index=False).sum() \
  .merge(df2.drop(['QV', 'QC'], 1))

   SKU        DATA   QV    QC  LOJA  PVENDA  ESTOQUE_VENDA  ESTOQUE_VENDA_UN_COMPRA CURVA_ABC  FORNECEDOR
0   70  2018-01-01  5.0  50.0  HD01   14.07          539.0                   5390.0         S        7355
1   70  2018-01-02  4.0  40.0  HD01   13.78          539.0                   5390.0         S        7355
2   70  2018-01-03  3.0  30.0  HD01   13.78          539.0                   5390.0         S        7355
```

Answer (score 3):

You should do `merge` rather than concat

```
df2.drop(['QV','QC'],1).merge(df1.groupby(['SKU', 'DATA'],as_index=Fasle).sum()
```

,on=['SKU','DATA'])

Comment: Hi @WeNYoBen, 

It worked fine, however, how to keep the columns from Dataframe 2 (that are not in common) ?

Comment: I don't know why the code doesn't keep it. The @piRSquared worked.